# Retrieve Queue position in sidekiq

Tags: redis, queue, sidekiq

I've skimmed through the docs but haven't found anything yet.

Is it possible the retrieve the current position of a given job within Sidekiq's queue?

My use case is **2 workers** over the **default queue** with hundreds of tasks of variable complexity. So if for example I submit a new task now and the queue size is say 10, how can I determine the position of my task after 5 minutes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without a linear scan of the entire queue; the position will change millisecond by millisecond as jobs are fetched and executed.

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new("default").each do |job|
  p job
end
```

Comment: Right. Thanks. So which would be the recommended way to show some sort of progress in such a scenario? (before a task is executed)

Comment: `Sidekiq::Queue.new.latency` will give you a lagging indicator of the queue wait time.